# using dynamic div in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to show the information in div which are stored in mysql table. But according to below code I get an error.

**code**

```
    <?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","internship");
    $sql="select * from vacancy";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        ?>
        <div class="bs-calltoaction bs-calltoaction-primary">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 cta-contents">
                    <h1 class="cta-title">Its a Call To Action</h1>
                    <div class="cta-desc">
                        <input type="text" value="job name" readonly style="width: 75%"><?php echo $row['catogary']; ?><br><br>
                        <input type="text" value="job name" readonly style="width: 75%"><?php echo $row['company_name']; ?><br><br>
                        <input type="text" value="job name" readonly style="width: 75%"><?php echo $row['location']; ?><br><br>
                        <input type="text" value="job name" readonly style="width: 75%"><?php echo $row['qulification']; ?><br><br>
                        <input type="text" value="job name" readonly style="width: 75%"><?php echo $row['catogary']; ?><br><br>
                        <input type="text" value="job name" readonly style="width: 37.5%"><?php echo $row['indate']; ?>&nbsp;
                        <input type="text"value="job name" readonly style="width: 37.5%"><?php echo $row['expdate']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 cta-button">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Apply for job</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump()` your result; your query may be failing